# How to make the main menu screen fade out when the game starts in libGDX?

Tags: libgdx, screen

I am creating the main menu of my game, and I want the main menu screen to disappears with a fade out. I thought that if I used a `Stage` to make the menu and added buttons as actors, the menu would work...

But I get the following problem: If I add the `fadeOut(1)` in the click event of the button used to start the game, instead of having the whole screen fade out, only the buttons of the menu disappear. Probably using `Stage` is the wrong way to make menus, and I do not know the right way ...

```
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.TextureRegion;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.InputEvent;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Stage;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.actions.Actions;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.ImageButton;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.utils.ClickListener;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.utils.Drawable;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.utils.TextureRegionDrawable;
import com.phillips.mrbulb.MrBulb;


public class MenuState extends Estado {
    private Stage menu;
    private Texture fondo;
    private Drawable empz, instr, acrc, slir;
    private ImageButton empezar, instrucciones, acerca, salir;
    public MenuState(GameStateManager gsm) {
        super(gsm);
        fondo = new Texture("fondo_temp.png");
        empz = new TextureRegionDrawable(new TextureRegion(new Texture("Empezar.png")));
        instr = new TextureRegionDrawable(new TextureRegion(new Texture("Instrucciones.png")));
        acrc = new TextureRegionDrawable(new TextureRegion(new Texture("Acerca.png")));
        slir = new TextureRegionDrawable(new TextureRegion(new Texture("Salir.png")));
        empezar = new ImageButton(empz);
        empezar.addCaptureListener(new ClickListener(){
            public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y){
                menu.addAction(Actions.fadeOut(1));
            }
        });
        empezar.setPosition(MrBulb.ANCHO/2 - 90,MrBulb.ALTO/2);
        instrucciones = new ImageButton(instr);
        instrucciones.setPosition(MrBulb.ANCHO/2 - 80,MrBulb.ALTO/2 - 90);
        acerca = new ImageButton(acrc);
        acerca.setPosition(MrBulb.ANCHO/2 - 62,MrBulb.ALTO/2 - 180);
        salir = new ImageButton(slir);
        salir.setPosition(MrBulb.ANCHO/2 - 33,MrBulb.ALTO/2 - 267);
        menu = new Stage();
        menu.addActor(empezar);
        menu.addActor(instrucciones);
        menu.addActor(acerca);
        menu.addActor(salir);
    }

    @Override
    public void update(float dt) {
        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(menu);
        handleInput();
    }

    @Override
    public void handleInput() {

    }

    @Override
    public void render(SpriteBatch batch) {
        batch.begin();
        batch.draw(fondo,0,0,MrBulb.ANCHO, MrBulb.ALTO);
        batch.end();
        menu.act(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());
        menu.draw();
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        fondo.dispose();
    }
}
```

What would be the correct way to make a menu for the game? Or, if using `Stage`, what would be the right way of coding it?

Comment: You have no other actors except for the buttons, what else do you want to disappear? The texture `fondo`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `fadeOut` is the way to go. You just need to make sure that everything that you want to fade out is part of your `Stage`. You should start by adding an `Image` instead of directly rendering your background.

```
menu = new Stage();

/* Create your background as an actor instead of just a texture */
Image background = new Image(fondo);
background.setBounds(0, 0, MrBulb.ANCHO, MrBulb.ALTO);

menu.addActor(empezar);
menu.addActor(instrucciones);
menu.addActor(acerca);
menu.addActor(salir);
menu.addActor(background);
```

This will now appropriately fade out your background as well as the buttons. Also make sure to remove these lines from your render method so you don't double-render the background:

```
batch.begin();
batch.draw(fondo,0,0,MrBulb.ANCHO, MrBulb.ALTO);
batch.end();
```